# CentOS - Check if it is updated

Tags: centos, software-updates

I just acquired a VPS and "installed" a CentOS 7 Minimal from the templates they make available.

[image]

After installation I am trying to update it, but receive this message **No packages marked for update**.

```
# yum update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * updates: ftpmirror.your.org
No packages marked for update
```

I already tried to use **yum clean all** and the "famous" **reboot**, but the message is allways the same.

I am wondering if the template image is really updated or I am doing something wrong. When listing the installed packages, almost all dates are from less than 2 months ago (today is Mon Sep  4 12:09:58 2017).

```
# rpm -qa --last

nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64                      Mon Sep  4 12:09:58 2017
gpg-pubkey-f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b                  Mon Sep  4 12:09:58 2017
man-pages-3.53-5.el7.noarch                   Tue Jul 25 04:40:18 2017
wget-1.14-13.el7.x86_64                       Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
vzdummy-systemd-el7-1.0-2.noarch              Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
vim-enhanced-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64         Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
unzip-6.0-16.el7.x86_64                       Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64                Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
tmpwatch-2.11-5.el7.x86_64                    Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
time-1.7-45.el7.x86_64                        Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
telnet-0.17-60.el7.x86_64                     Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
tcsh-6.18.01-13.el7_3.1.x86_64                Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
tcpdump-4.5.1-3.el7.x86_64                    Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
talk-0.17-46.el7.x86_64                       Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
stunnel-4.56-6.el7.x86_64                     Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
rootfiles-8.1-11.el7.noarch                   Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
ntsysv-1.7.2-1.el7_3.1.x86_64                 Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
ncompress-4.2.4.4-3.el7.x86_64                Tue Jul 25 04:40:16 2017
...
```

Here is my **CentOS-Base.repo** file:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Is this an issue (misconfiguration) or the template is really updated?

Comment: Looks plausible, as CentOS' upstream RHEL has made a minor step to 7.4 which CentOS hasn't followed yet, so there's a bit of a lull in updates.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, the command "cat /etc/centos-release" gives me: "CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)". So you think the template is really updated? My only concern is about security (I am taking another actions about security, but the OS update is one of primary steps I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining my comments above into something resembling an answer: No, there's no reason to be worried.

- If `yum` wanted to download and was simply refused by a proxy, you'd see an error message.
- CentOS is currently (early September '17) in the final steps of going from 7.3.1611 to 7.4.1708. The upstream project RHEL went from 7.3 to 7.4 about a month or so ago, so there's not much by way of updates coming from them anymore, that's why you currently see very few, if any, updates on CentOS 7.3.
- You can always check the mirror servers directly: if you look at, e.g., http://ftp.fau.de/centos/7/updates/x86_64/drpms/, there's no files with a change date in August or September '17 right now, which might confirm that you're not missing out on anything.

Once CentOS 7.4 is released, you'll notice it as a big bunch of updates (like, several hundred, or "pretty much everything") coming in all at once, and just doing `yum update` will move you to 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you can get online

```
ping google.com
```

Assuming you get some feedback e.g.

```
64 bytes from lhr35s04-blah-blah.net (213.58.203.68) icmp_seq....
```

Then the feedback you got is correct - there's nothing else to update.
If you can't get online, then it's doing so!

Comment: Thank you for helping. Do you think firewall could block yum update? I tried to install UFW on CentOS 7...

Comment: The firewall shouldn't block yum unless it's gone into panic mode or something akin.